# How do I see the console.log in this code?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, console.log

```js
var hexBeat;

function clarity() {
  setInterval(function() {
    function randomNumber(min, max) {
      return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
      hexBeat = randomNumber(1, 25);
      console.log(hexBeat);
    }
  }, 1000)
}

while (hexBeat <= 20) {
  document.querySelector("#nachoCheddar01").style.backgroundColor = "green";
  document.querySelector("#nachoCheddar01").style.left = "200px";
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <button onClick="clarity()" style="z-index:1">click for random number in console</button>
  <div id="nachoCheddar01" style="z-index: -1; box-sizing:border-box;border:3px solid green;background-color: blue;position:absolute;top:1%;height:100px;width:200px;">NachoCheddar01</div>
  <div id="nachoCheddar02" style="">NachoCheddar02</div>
  <div id="nachoCheddar03" style="">NachoCheddar03</div>
  <div id="nachoCheddar04" style="">NachoCheddar04</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to log hexBeat, then based on that I would like to move the rectangle to the right on the screen every time there is a random number less than or equal to 20, and also change its color. But right now I'm failing to get the console.log(hexBeat)
I tried declaring the variable outside of any function. I'm trying to use that variable, hexBeat inside another function, and I have had success declaring my variables like that. Although, I'm using intervals, and I'm not sure if there is a better way to approach moving the rectangle every time there is a random number less than or equal to 20.

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded. The interval function won't run until the `while` loop stops. But the while loop won't stop until the interval function increments `hexBeat`. Do you see the problem with that?

Comment: Put what you want to do in the interval function, not a separate loop.

Comment: Also, the call to `randomNumber()` should not be *inside* the definition of `randomNumber()`.

Comment: How does your code move the rectangle to the right? It just keeps setting its position to the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your code like this:

HTML:

```
<html>

<body>

  <button onClick="clarity()" style="z-index:1">click for random number in console</button>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="nachoCheddar01" style="z-index: -1; box-sizing:border-box;border:3px solid green;background-color: blue;position:absolute;top:1%;height:100px;width:200px;">NachoCheddar01</div>
    <div id="nachoCheddar02" style="">NachoCheddar02</div>
    <div id="nachoCheddar03" style="">NachoCheddar03</div>
    <div id="nachoCheddar04" style="">NachoCheddar04</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#nachoCheddar01 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var hexBeat;

function clarity() {
  setInterval(function() {
    function randomNumber(min, max) {
      return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    }
    hexBeat = randomNumber(1, 25);
    if (hexBeat <= 20) {
      console.log(hexBeat);
      document.querySelector("#nachoCheddar01").style.backgroundColor = "green";
      document.querySelector("#nachoCheddar01").style.left = `${document.querySelector("#nachoCheddar01").offsetLeft + 200}px`;
    }
    
  }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: This will keep the box at the same value as suggested Barmar, you have to update the css to move right side everytime the number is changed

Comment: this is working well to move the rectangles initially but i'm trying to assign a new left value every time a new number is randomized

Comment: updated code above, 
Also can checkout this:
https://jsbin.com/hacenelazu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: the nacho04 is not moving though i haven't seen a number past 60 i tried matching up the min with min and max with max, but no luck